# Write CSV file into vectors in C (continued)

Tags: c++

Basically I have 14800x8 matrix that has been extracted from matlab as CSV file ("moves.mo"). I need to read this file into 14800 vectors with 8 values each.
Here is a few lines from the file:

```
1,2,3,4,-1,-3,-2,-4
1,2,3,5,-1,-3,-2,-5
1,2,3,6,-1,-3,-2,-6
1,2,3,7,-1,-3,-2,-7
1,2,3,8,-1,-3,-2,-8
1,2,3,9,-1,-3,-2,-9
```

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <istream>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{



        std::fstream inputfile;
        inputfile.open("moves.da");
        std::vector< std::vector<int> > vectorsmovesList; //declare vector list


        while (inputfile) {

            std::string s;
            if (!getline( inputfile, s )) break;

            istringstream ss( s );
            vector <int> recordmove;

            while (ss)
            {

                if (!getline( ss, s, ',' )) break;
                int recordedMoveInt = atoi(s.c_str());
                recordmove.push_back( recordedMoveInt );
            }

            vectorsmovesList.push_back( recordmove );
        }
        if (!inputfile.eof())
        {
            cerr << "Fooey!\n";
        }
```

It compiles but does not give me desirable output (i.e. just prints Fooey!) . I don't know why... This problem at this point is driving me insane.

Please help!

Comment: It's nice to have a link to the previous post, but you shouldn't require others to follow it in order to understand this question. Please make the question self-contained.

Comment: You might also want to explain what's wrong; "it is not working" isn't much to go on.

Comment: I'm sorry, but, "does not give me desirable output," is hardly any better.

Comment: I've edited the post to use a more idiomatic coding style. It should behave exactly the same, however, so I doubt that it fixes anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are better ways to read integers in C++.  For example:

```
std::string s;
if (!getline( inputfile, s )) break;
istringstream ss( s );
int recordedMove;
while (ss >> recordedMove)
{
    recordmove.push_back(recordedMove);
    // consume the commas between integers.  note if there are no 
    // separating commas, you will lose some integers here.
    char garbage; 
    ss >> garbage;
}
```

Also, you're not printing out your result anywhere.  Here's how you would do it:

```
vector<vector<int> >::const_iterator ii;
for (ii = vectorsmovesList.begin(); ii != vectorsmovesList.end(); ++ii)
{
    vector<int>::const_iterator jj;
    for (jj = ii->begin(); jj != ii->end(); ++jj)
        cout << *jj << ' ';
    cout << endl;
}
```

Obviously, you'd do that after you've parsed and closed the CSV file.

Comment: I replaced the double-declaration, but because it's bad style, not because it's a bug, which it isn't.

Comment: @misha, Thank you. Unfortunately it is not even printing the result.... I checked the input file and it is there in the directory.

Comment: Did you add the printing code that I wrote?  If I add that to your result, then it prints the first integer in the line.  If I replace the inner loop with a working integer parsing step, then if prints out all the integers in the CSV file.  This is all using a home-made CSV file, which may be different to yours.  Post your CSV file if you think that's part of the problem.

Comment: Where can I post the file? I am new to this :)

Comment: Just take the top 10 lines and put in your answer.  Don't forget to format it as code.

Comment: You need to understand that "it is not working" is a phrase that is typically loathed here.  You need to say **what exactly** is not working: what you saw, what you expected to see, and what the difference between the two is.  Without those bits of information, most people won't want to help you.

Comment: @misha I am sorry :) I get 'Fooey!' as an output. Of course I expect to see a list of vectors.

Comment: The only time you will get "Fooey!" as output is if the file is not opened correctly, or in case of an I/O error.  Check that your file is located in your present working directory.

Comment: ok, I think it was a syntax mistake on my side! yay! the progress is there, now I got an output, however it is just one long column of numbers in the same exact order as in the file.

Comment: if you're using the integer parsing code that i provided, then see my updated answer.  there was an error -- replace `string garbage` with `char garbage`.